# Max over time pooling in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using CNNs in `Keras` for an NLP task and instead of max pooling, I'm trying to achieve max over time pooling.

Any ideas/hacks on how to achieve this?

What I mean by max over time pooling is to pool the highest value, no matter where they are in the vector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your data shape is `(batch_size, seq_len, features)` you may apply:

```
seq_model = Reshape((seq_len * features, 1))(seq_model)
seq_model = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(seq_model)
```

Comment: @bluesummers Does it really answer on your question? Look at model.summary(). You will receive ONE max value, not 'the highest n values'.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev, you won't receive max value, the input is in the shape of (samples, steps, features), and output is (samples, features) - this is not restricted to 1 max value

Comment: @bluesummers Your question is interesting and I'm trying to understand. Look at this code: `model=Sequential([Embedding(500,10,input_length=5),Reshape((5*10,1)),GlobalMaxPooling1D()]);model.summary()` Output shape at the end = (None, 1). `None` is equivalent of batch_size or samples. Features = 1. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, I was in my writing, what I meant is that you won't necessarily get 1 max **value**, you get 1 max tensor. So you can get a vector of length n as output from the GlobalMaxPooling1D - that was the n I referred to - I will edit the question

Comment: @bluesummers Ahh, okay. Thank you for clarification.