# keras max pooling layer after embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have a 7 word embedding, each in dimension 10, so overall I have a matrix of 7 rows and 10 columns.
After applying this embedding (using embedding layer), I get the output of dimension (None, 7, 1, 10).

I want to have a vector, such that its i'th element is the maximum of row i, for each i in the range of {0,6}. Hence, it should be a vector of length 7 (and dimension like (None,7)).

For this purpose, I first use a reshape layer, to change dimension to (7,10) (otherwise, it does not work).

Then, I've tried to use GlobalMaxPooling1D for this purpose (also tried MaxPooling1D), and the output does not
have the dimension that I wanted. It is  (None, 10) instead of (None,7).

I've checked the GlobalMaxPooling1D on a separate example, and it works well. It must be something with the additional dimension that the embedding layer pushes in the middle.

p.s. A similar question has been asked here:
[Max over time pooling in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958115/max-over-time-pooling-in-keras)
But I don't think that the suggested answer there answer the original question (it seems to return the maximum of the entire matrix).

[image]

Comment: Try with Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_max(x, axis=-1)) instead of GlobalMaxPooling1D()

Comment: Thanks! I did thought of Lambda layer, but tried amax function that does the same as tf.reduce_max, but it had some numpy - tensors errors, that your suggestion does not have.